# Chart JS Line Graph multitooltipkey background color issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

I have a question about Chart.js. I am using a line graph with 2 sets of data (2 lines) and when i hover over the data it shows the "legend". In the legend are  2 boxes that can be colored. I can change the background color of the boxes with no issue but when I change the color it applies to both boxes. How can I set the color of the box separately? Thanks.

```
    <canvas
    class="ex-line-graph"
    width="1200" height="1200"
    data-chart="line"
    data-scale-start-value="0"
    data-scale-step-width ="100"
    data-scale-steps ="4"
    data-point-fill-color = "RGBA( 255,28,221,.3)"
    data-scale-line-color="transparent"
    data-scale-grid-line-color="rgba(255,255,255,.05)"
    data-scale-font-color="#a2a2a2"
    data-labels="         ['April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December        ','January','February','March']"
    data-value="[{ fillColor: 'RGBA( 28,168,221,.3)', strokeColor:      
    '#1CA8DD', label:'Data', data: [151, 154, 173, 169, 176,161,0,0,0,0,0,0]}, {fillColor: 'RGBA(37,40,48,.0)', strokeColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)', label :'Target', data: [200, 200,200,200,200, 200,200,200,200, 200,200,200] }]">
  </canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a 2 part answer if I follow correctly:

1.- Specify colors on your data set:

```
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Series A",
    data: [10, 30, 20, 40, 10],
    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.8)",
    backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,255,0.5)"
  }, {
    label: "Series B",
    data: [25, 40, 10, 40, 30],
    borderColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)",
    backgroundColor:"rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"
  }]
};
```

And enable the tooltips on the options Object (Notice the mode Label):

```
var options = {
  tooltips: {
   enabled: true,
   mode: 'label'
 },          
  legend: {
    display: true,
  }  
};
```

Result:

[image: Chart.js label tooltips]

Codepen:

[Codepen - Chart.js Multiline Tooltip labels](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/bwmGVA?editors=1010)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a HTML answer however. I forgot to mention that. My apologies.

Comment: @user45481: Chart.js  configuration is done through Javascript, you give it a canvas with your options and it builds you a chart in HTML, are you sure you are using Chart.js ?

Comment: Yes. When I changed multi tooltip key background in chart.js it changes both legend box colors. If I entered 2 colors it made both the first color. I need a way to define them separately.